# Submission to gerrit fails with "Change is Closed" message

Tags: git, egit, gerrit

I am working through eGIT
I had submitted some changes in the gerrit. This change "B" was dependent on a change"A" which was already abandoned.
Then it got merge conflict error

So i fetched the changed through "Fetch from Gerrit" by creating a new branch with the Gerrit change "B". Then i rebased the whole branch "B" with the "origin/master" such that i get the latest code. I resolved all the conflicts meanwhile during rebase.Now when i submit the patch set for Change "B" then i get change "A" (Which was already abandoned before i submitted this gerrit "B" change) closed error.

My Question is how Change "A" which was already abandoned before i submitted Change "B" patch set1 is giving error when i am submitting CHange "B" patch set 2.

Also how do i remove the abandoned changes from my gerrit request "B" ?

cheers,
Saurav

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that your rebased change B has Change-Id tag of the abandoned change A. It could have got there during squashing, for example. If this is so, amend the commit message to remove Change-Id (your local Gerrit commit hook will then generate a new one) and try pushing again.

Comment: thanks spbnick for the answer. I had tried that it did not work :(

Comment: @saurav Do you have any changes on top of change B that you're pushing? Could it be that *they* have been closed? Can you try pushing changes *before* change B only? Could it be that *they* are causing the failure?

Comment: Change A had touched same files which have been changed in Change B. Now Change A i have abandoned, i dont want the changes to get it. The history view in eGIT shows commit in Change A as parent of commit in Change B. I want to get rid of commit in Change A and the change A itself

Comment: @saurav So, the problem is that you still have change A and are pushing it. Sorry, I never used eGIT, but with bare git you can just run `git rebase -i change_a^` and remove the line with change A.

Comment: Thanks a lot sbnick for your help. I did not get any way to get rid of the previous commit. So  i just did hard reset with the origin/master and then made the changes again and submitted.